# Weird Shadows on my donut cycles render

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, eevee-render-engine, lighting, shadows

[image]

I'm new to blender and I'm following this donut tutorial, but when I render in cycles I get these weird rectangular shadows and I can't fix them. I get them in Eevee too

Comment: What are you using as a light source?

Comment: I use a point light and even when I try varying its power or other variables, it doesnt change much

Comment: What is your light radius? It should be 0.1 by default. Anything over 0.7 seems to cause similar looking shadows for me (at least at the distance I have the light).

Comment: Problem solved. Huge difference. Thank you!